# Как в hibernate связать две таблицы по определенному полю, используя аннотацию

Tags: java, hibernate

Как в hibernate сделать связку таблицы один к одному 
через определенное поле, например `table_1(id,city,number)` и `table_2(id,city,name)` по полю `city`.

Я делал так, ничего не получилось, `Set` не заполнялся:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="speople")
public class People {
    @Id()
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int ID;

    @Column(name="city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="city",insertable = false,updatable = false)
__________________________________________________________
@Entity
@Table(name="smoreinfo")

public class Moreinfo {
    @Id()
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;


    @Column(name ="city")
    String city;

    @Column(name="phone")
    Long number;


    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy = "moreinfo",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "city")
   Set<People> people;
```

Если связывать через id, то все работает.

Comment: @ManyToOne не нужно здесь, попробуйте это, [например](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21762328/java-hibernate-onetoone-mapping)

Comment: 1. приведите сущности целиком. 2. какой тип связи?